# Using GitHub for Windows with MSysGit

Tags: windows-8, git, context-menu

I have both [GitHub for Windows](https://windows.github.com/) and [MSysGit](https://msysgit.github.io/) installed on my PC.

As GitHub for Windows provides its own copy of Git, I feel as if having MSysGit also installed is redundant. However, I enjoy the context menu features that MSysGit provides:

> [image: mysysgit's context menu]

I am aware that GitHub for Windows stores its copy of Git in `C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/GitHub` and its folders look something like this:

> [image: github installation directory]

Given my problem, is there a way to either:

- **Configure GitHub for Windows to use my MSysGit installation instead of its own? (and delete the Git installation that GitHub for Windows provides?)**

or

- **Somehow create a MSysGit-like context menu (perhaps via registry keys) that points to GitHub for Windows's Git installation?**

Comment: Just modify the context menus to point to the other installation.  I would post an answer but I am not willing to invest time to create a step by step tutorial.

Comment: You are aware both installations are installing the same version of Git on Windows right?  One just adds those context menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this was to uninstall MSysGit and edit the registry to create a context menu option that points to the GitHub for Windows installation.

The following script created the option for me:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\directory\shell\git_bash]
@="Open with Git Ba&sh"
; optional: set "Icon" key to change the icon of the option

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\directory\shell\git_bash\command]
@="\"C:\\WINDOWS\\SysWOW64\\wscript.exe\" \"C:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\Local\\GitHub\\PortableGit_<guid>\\Git Bash.vbs\" \"%1\""
```

(`<username>` is my username and `<guid>` is the string of letters and numbers in the `PortableGit_` folder name)

It gets pretty involved since the installation location is different for everyone so I created a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/theoctopod/a9e07c1f0bfe193f47fe) that provides instructions to anyone else that comes across the same problem.